# How to run an if condition only once for a specific user?

Tags: php, session

```
session_start();
$result = query("SELECT *FROM users");
confirm($result);

while($row = fetch_assoc($result)){
    $id = $row['userId'];
    $level = $row['level'];
    $rs = query("SELECT *FROM income 
                WHERE user_id = '$id'");
    confirm($rs);
    $inc = fetch_assoc($rs);
    if($level == 2 && !isset($_SESSION['l2'.$id])){
        $cal = $inc['incentive']+170; 
        $_SESSION['l2'.$id] = 1;
        confirm(query("UPDATE income SET incentive='$cal' WHERE user_id='$id'"));
    }else
        if($level == 3 && !isset($_SESSION['l3'.$id])){
            $cal = $inc['incentive']+430; 
            $_SESSION['l3'.$id] = 1;
            confirm(query("UPDATE income SET incentive='$cal' WHERE user_id='$id'"));
        }
```

There are thousands of users, in this code it will create thousands of sessions, any one can help me to write an efficient code.

Comment: Start by coding one line of code on each line and indenting your code so it can be read ___and therefore maintained and debugged easily___

Comment: Also if your code contains functions that are not vanilla PHP then also show us what they do, by this I mean `confirm()` and `fetch_assoc()` and `query()` and any I may have missed

Comment: Finally, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: And also use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: And if you are using `$_SESSION[]` in your code, confirm that you have also run a `start_session()` or that will be the forst thing people suggest may be wrong

Comment: Is there any field on the `users` table that lets you query on that one user (like an email or a first name/last name)?  If so, you could let the SQL server do the heavy lifting and find the user you're looking for.